# React typescript passing function as prop and calling from child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm passing in a function to a child component, that manages my state in the parent component. It takes an object, that is declared in FriendListItem and sets it to the array as a new object. I have been researching but can not figure it out.

```
interface FriendListItem {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  address: string;
}
```

the function

```
 const [friendList, setFriendList] = useState<FriendListItem[]>([]);

  const addToFriendList = (friend: FriendListItem): void => {
    setFriendList((prevstate) => [...prevstate, friend]);
  };
```

I'm passing it to the child component

```
<UserDetail addFriend={addToFriendList} />
```

and this is my child component code, I'm telling (or trying to) the component, the function will take friend arg and return void. But when I pass that in I get an error

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'FuncProps' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

Code:

```
interface FriendListItem {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  address: string;
}

interface FuncProps {
  addFriend: (friend: FriendListItem) => void;
}

const UserDetail = (addFriend: FuncProps) => {
  const { userId } = useParams<UserIdParams>();
  const { data, done } = useFetchOne(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${userId}`
  );

  const handleClick = () => {
    const friend: FriendListItem = {
      id: data!.id,
      name: data!.name,
      address: data!.address.street,
    };
    addFriend(friend);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first argument of your component is an object, which contains passed props, you have to get it from props object, e.g:

```
interface UserDetailProps {
   addFriend: FuncProps
}

connst UserDetail: FC<UserDetailProps> = ({addFriend}) => {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to change it as

```
const UserDetail = ({addFriend}: FuncProps) => { ... }
```

or

```
const UserDetail: React.FC<FuncProps> = ({addFriend}) => { .... }
```